# Gradle: dependency management for custom source set

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management

I have a spring boot module. The module has spring boot plugin version 2.7.x:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.18"
}

dependencies {
    api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure")
    api("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")
}
```

I have also created a [source set](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-source-sets) for some Spring Boot 3.2 specific code:

```
val springBoot32 = sourceSets.create("main-spring-boot-3.2")
springBoot32.compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
tasks.jar.get().from(springBoot32.output)
```

Within dependencies block I declared dependencies for Spring Boot 3.2 source set:

```
springBoot32Implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:3.2.1")
springBoot32Implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:3.1.1")
```

The configuration above works well, however I have to manually declare versions for every dependency rather than using [spring boot BOM](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies).

I am looking for something like this:

```
springBoot32Implementation(platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.2.1"))
springBoot32Implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure")
springBoot32Implementation("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka")
```

However this configuration doesn't work - all dependencies within Spring Boot 3.2 source set are still from Spring Boot 2.7 plugin.

Is there any way to employ `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies` to manage dependency versions for custom source set?